# Sorting Array Items using filter disaligning the old items from their elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-redux

Im a beginner and Ive been doing some todo app with redux, and my problem is when I, for example, input a value to textbox, "sample" lets say, and I input another string, "sample2" then I input again the "sample", the "sample" wc I inputted earlier doesnt duplicate, but it moves to the bottom instead of steadying at her place,

Here's some basic interface for my todo:

//assume theres a textbox here...

Sample

Sample2

Sample3

Then when I input a 'Sample' again, assuming that I duplciate the first one, here it is now:

Sample2

Sample3

Sample

The 'Sample' wc at the top moves to bottom instead of steadying at her place

Heres my reducer for adding a todo:

```
switch (action.type) ...
// adding todo
...  (todo = [], action) => { 
  return [ 
//logic for not duplicating the word
  ...todos.filter(todo => 
  todo.content.toLowerCase() !== 
  action.payload.toLowerCase()),

  { content: action.payload
  ...}
]
}
```

Should I try any methods instead of filter in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are filtering the content.
Its normal the first sample is not return. Since you are spreading the old value with spread operator

```
 filter(todo => 
  todo.content.toLowerCase() !== 
  action.payload.toLowerCase()
      action.payload.toLowerCase()
```

means that if there is item of same value reject that value.

Comment: Okay get it man! Thanks! Is there a way so the 'Sample' wont be moved at the bottom?

Comment: The thing is that the old SAMPLE is removed and The new SAMPLE is added.
The New SAMPLE IS added to the bottom.
The Bottom SAMPLE is not the old one.

{{  The old one does not move its got filtered away }}